# Custom onepage checkout magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, custom

I am struggling to create magento 2 custom one page checkout like in the screenshots i attached i simple design the page with html and css, but i really dont know how do i implement functionality on it.Here is the design please help me how can i achieve this. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should edit CSS of the existing checkout. You can't implement functionality in a written template.

First of all, I advise you to install One Step Checkout extension from a famous vendor (Amasty, AheadWorks, Mageplaza etc).  Because by default Magento 2 doesn't allow to display all steps on one page. After that, all you need is editing CSS styles.

I hope it will help.

Comment: is there any professional free onepage checkout? that you recommend me..

Comment: I'm using the extension from AheadWorks. Amasty is also was good for me. As I remember Amasty has one column template. So it is similar with your template. 

https://amasty.com/one-step-checkout-for-magento-2.html

Comment: but its too expensive can you share a free version.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, all Magento 2 extensions are expensive :(